# Результаты цикла в списке

Tags: python, парсер

Всем привет! ниже код с циклами, который выгружает все в список.

```
result = []
coins = ["BTC", "USDT", "ETH"]
list_bank = ["BUY", "SELL"]
list_bank1 = ["RosBankNew", "TinkoffNew", "QIWI"]
for asset in coins:
    for tradeType in list_bank:
        for payTypes in list_bank1:
            binance(asset, tradeType, payTypes)
            result.append(binance(asset, tradeType, payTypes))
            result.sort()
```

Вывод получается вот такой:

```
 ['169476.60', '170340.00', '170720.10', '171700.00', '171700.00', '174250.00', '2676000.00', '2678381.76', '2684827.02', '2699980.00', '2700000.00', '2725000.00', '91.94', '92.02', '92.04', '92.08', '92.12', '92.48']
```

Мне нужно, что бы каждый результат выводился с названием переменных, которые были применены в цикле.

Например возьмём первый результат из списка: 169476.60, мне нужно что бы вывелось примерно так:
169476.60 Buy RosBankNew или Sell RosBankNew.
Мне нужно подписать каждый результат переменными, которые были применены. Всем хорошего настроения! Надеюсь на вашу помощь)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну тогда и добавляйте кортежем все нужные поля, а не только цену:

```
result.append((binance(asset, tradeType, payTypes), asset, tradeType, payTypes))
```

И сортировку делайте уже после завершения циклов, зачем вы на каждом шаге цикла сортируете, ни к чему это.

Кстати, сортировка у вас не числовая, а лексикографическая, как вы уже, наверное, заметили. Потому что у вас строки, а не числа.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! Я новичок, все ваши советы учту, огромная благодарность!